# How to boot Windows from new hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, windows-8.1, uefi

I just bought a new, bigger hard drive. Currently I'm running Windows 8.1 with a 1TB hard drive. I just bought a new 3TB hard drive and installed it in my computer. Everything seems OK and Windows sees my new hard drive.

What I wanted to do was clone my current drive onto my new drive, then boot off my new drive. I went and downloaded [Farstone's DriveClone](http://www.farstone.com/software/drive-clone.php) to clone my drive. That seemed to work just fine.

My issue is, I go to reboot my machine and enter the BIOS (its an UEFI BIOS) and I go to the boot menu to select which drive to boot off of and the only option my BIOS is giving me is to boot from my original 1TB drive. The BIOS sees the new hard drive, but it just won't let me boot from it. I'm a newbie when it comes to UEFI and I suspect there is something I'm missing to allow it to boot from the new drive. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

In case you need to know, my computer is an [ASUS m51ac-us004s](http://www.asus.com/us/Desktops/M51AC/). What I'd like to do, if cloning isn't possible, is to just start from scratch and reinstall Windows 8.1. Unfortunately, I do not have any DVDs for Windows.

Comment: Look in bios after an option to specify hard drive order, often it's a separate option from the one that sets boot order

Comment: @Dan - I have a boot menu along the top and when I go into that menu, it has "Boot Priority" and it only has my one hard drive listed. That is the only boot menu I see.

Comment: Let me get this straight. Go to bios, advanced mode, boot tab, boot option priorities, boot option #1, you cannot select the desired hdd?

Comment: @Dan - Correct. It shows just my original 1TB hard drive. If I go to the Main screen in the bios, I see both hard drives. Also, from Windows 8.1, I can see both hard drives. But for some reason, I can only boot from the first hard drive. The original 1TB hard drive

Answer (score 0):

Switch the SATA cables and let me know if the other hard drive becomes bootable. Your clone might not be working either, but I'd try the cables first.

Comment: I already tried switching the SATA cables. Same result.

Comment: Then see if the bootmgr is missing. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/209885-bootmgr-move-c-easybcd.html